# El texto de TextView se ve cortado

Tags: android, xml

Tengo un **LinearLayout** y sus elementos que se encuentran dentro del él no marcan error, pero tengo un problema con unos **TextView** ya que el texto se ve un poco cortado.

> Código

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutcantidad2"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/title_text_view_spum"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewROUnidad"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSPUM"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutcantidad"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewRecibir"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_cantidad_empaque"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextCantidadRecibir"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:maxLength="10"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:digits="0123456789."
                    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewUnidadMedida"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_small_um"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_ultimo_escaneado"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_acumulado_u"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_ValorEscaneado"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Lbl_ValorAcumulado"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**El contenido de estos TextView se ven cortados**

```html
<TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
                    android:paddingStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_ultimo_escaneado"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:text="@string/title_text_view_acumulado_u"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: ¿Cortados en los extremos, arriba, abajo? Considera agregar una imagen para que los miembros de la comunidad puedan ver lo que esta sucediendo.

Comment: Exacto, si no añades una imagen no se puede ver tal efecto. Seguro que es sencillo de solucionar. Salu2